# Parallelizing tests with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, continuous-delivery, continuous-testing

I am using Jenkins for integration testing.

Just to give the context. At the moment I have a separate build server which produces the build daily and Jenkins is not used as the build server. The build server executes the unit testing in my case.

- When build process is complete it invokes the Jenkins job. In that job Jenkins start to deploy the build into the Virtual machine. I have a script for doing this.
- Followed to that my plan is to run several scripts for doing the end-to-end testing.

Now I have several question in this regard:

- How to parallelize the execution of the end-to-end tests?
- As I am adding scripts after script I am getting worried how manageable it will be?
- I am always using the web interface for adding and changing the scripts. How to do this from the command line?

Any ideas for a good tutorial? Any pointers from all of you? Thanks!

Looks like Build Flow Plugin is what I need.
https://github.com/jenkinsci/build-flow-plugin

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try and see if you can use the Build Pipeline plugin before build flow. Much better visualization of what is going on, less scripting.

I link Build and deploy jobs in one sequence and then have unit and integration test jobs linked separately off the build job. You can then use Fail The Build plugin to have downstream jobs fail upstream ones.